# ActionBarSherlock EditText layout issue on 3.1

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I'm having a problem with EditText layout on 3.1 or above. I'm using the default style for EditText, on < 3.1 it works fine, but in 3.1 it seems that the style of EditText has been changed to a transparent background with a different border. Also, if the EditText is password type, the border just shows on bottom of the EditText. What am I missing?

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/user"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="" >
```

Comment: or how can I change the ActionBarSherlock style to the default one?

Comment: This is not ActionBarSherlock related as it has no styles related to the `EditText` widget.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out what caused your problem?